# how to specify a range or set of Listen in Apache httpd.conf file

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I am trying to get multiple ports to work with httpd.conf file

```
Listen 31
Listen 32
Listen 33
Listen 34
Listen 35
Listen 36
Listen 38
```

Is there a way to specify a range of ports in httpd.conf file
for example,

```
Listen 31-38
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifying every port seems to be the only option

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mpm_common.html#listen

Comment: There is suppose to be some kind of httpd.conf regular expression?